# How to get correct ordered console output in WPF-Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I want to use my WPF-Application to also work as a command line tool. So when you start it with no arguments it will open a WPF-Window. When using an Argument, it will just do the thing and post the results to the console.

So far so good.

I use this code to

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if (e.Args.Length == 1)
    {
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        var file = e.Args[0];
        // stuff I do
        string results = "All the stuff I have done"
            
        Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + results);
    }
    else
    {
        new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
    }

    

    this.Shutdown();
}
```

The problem is when I start it from cmd.exe the output looks like this:

```
C:\Svn\CSharp\MyExe\bin\Debug>MyExe.exe "Hallo"

C:\Svn\CSharp\MyExe\bin\Debug>
All the stuff I have done
```

This is obviosuly the wrong order: It should look like this:

```
C:\Svn\CSharp\MyExe\bin\Debug>MyExe.exe "Hallo"
All the stuff I have done   
C:\Svn\CSharp\MyExe\bin\Debug>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For non-console programs, the command shell does not wait for the process to exit.
You can use `start /wait MyExe.exe "Hallo"` to force the wait for exit.

Comment: ok...but this is quite hard to tell the enduser that he cant use it like he ist used to.

Answer (score 0):

in your app.xaml remove the need for the main window to close. this way you close it. Main window is created in OnStartUp,

```
<Application x:Class="My.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
             StartupUri="MainPage.xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Anything you do in the constructor of the application will control if it calls OnStartUp

public partial class App : Application
{
public App()
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
....
}

You can get the
Then you will always get arguments when the application starts, however, you can see by taking all but the first argument as the first argument is the full path to the executable

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 1)
{
    var file = string.Join(" ", args[1..]);
    _myFile = new FileInfo(file);
}
```

if you like to render the main window... else set it to Null

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = new Window2();

Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
```

As to you capturing the output in the correct order.. sound like something conserving the starting process.
Have a look at this extension method

```
public static Task<(bool runOk, string output)> RunProcessWithOutputAsync(this FileInfo path, string? args = null)
{
    if (path.Exists == false)
    {
        return Task.FromResult((false, "file not found"));
    }

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<(bool failed, string output)>();
    var process = new Process
    {
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path.FullName)
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Arguments = args ?? string.Empty
        }

    };
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
    };
    process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            var errorMessage = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) == false)
            {
                tcs.SetResult((false,errorMessage));
                tcs.SetException(new InvalidOperationException("The process did not exit correctly. The corresponding error message was: " + errorMessage));
            }
            tcs.SetResult((true,process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()));

        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetResult((true,process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()));
        }
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exit code:{process.ExitCode}");
        }
        process.Dispose();
    };
    process.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "ping.exe"));
var pong=await info.RunProcessWithOutputAsync("facebook.de");
Assert.IsTrue(pong.runOk);
```

Let me know if I did not understand your question